# how to call drawrect in UIView variable in a subclass of UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawrect

I created a subclass of UIView, in this class i declare a UIView variable.
I wanna call DrawRect of my UIView variable, because now when when i call DrawRect, it draws on my UIView class, not UIView variable, how can i do that?

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 5):

You don't call `drawRect`, you call `setNeedsDisplay` on your subview.

Comment: Suppose you have `UIView *subview1` which is a subview of `mainView`. In this case, whenever you need to redraw your `subview1`, you call [subview1 setNeedsDisplay] in your `mainView`'s implementation. Given that your `subview1` implementation has `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method overridden, it will be called.

Answer (score 3):

You have a UIViewCustomClass in which there is also a UIView ? Something like this :

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{
  AnotherView *aView;
}
```

That's right ?

So if you want to redraw the "aView" variable you have to override the setNeedsDisplay method in you MyView class :

.h

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{
      AnotherView *aView;
}

- (void)setNeedsDisplay;
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect) r;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyView

- (void)setNeedsDisplay
{
  [super setNeedsDisplay];
  [aView setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect) rect
{
  //Do your own custom drawing for the current view
}

@end
```

**Edit:**
Here, aView si a custom class too (type of AnotherView), so you can override draw rect method as we do previsouly with MyViewClass :

in AnotherView.m :

```
@implemetation AnotherView

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect) rect
{
  //Do drawing for your aView variable ;)
}

@end
```

According to apple guideline you should NEVER call drawRect directly (cf [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect%3a))

Comment: thanks, but how can i draws on my UIView variable?, i mean how can draw for example a line on my UIView Variable?

Comment: You'll need to sublcass your variable too and override the drawRect method.